# ReactJS Typescript Material UI Dialog Reusable Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Please assist me. I was creating a Reusable Material UI Modal Dialog component so that I can call it from any component but it is not showing whenever I click the button on any component. See the code below :

```
*********************THE MODAL COMPONENT

--->ReusableDialog.tsx

import React, { useState, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { createStyles, Theme, withStyles, WithStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Button,
    Dialog,
    DialogTitle,
    DialogContent,
    DialogContentText,
    DialogActions } from '@mui/material';

import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

type Props = {      
    show: boolean,
    title: string,
    body: ReactNode,      
    onSubmitButtonClicked: () => void;       
    closeDialog: () => void;   
};

export default function AppModalDialog(Props: Props) {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(Props.show)

    return <>    
<Dialog 
open={Props.show}
onClose = {() => setOpen(false)}
aria-labelledby='dialog-title'
aria-describedby='dialog-description'
>
<DialogTitle id='dialog-title'> {Props.title} </DialogTitle>
<DialogContent>
<DialogContentText id='dialog-description' >{Props.body}</DialogContentText>
</DialogContent>
<DialogActions>

<Button onClick={() =>Props.closeDialog}>Cancel</Button>
<Button autoFocus onClick={() => Props.onSubmitButtonClicked()}>Submit</Button>
</DialogActions>
</Dialog>
    </>
}

*************************THE FORM THAT WILL DISPLAY IN THE MODAL

childFormDialog.tsx

interface paymentTypeProps{
    paymenttype: string;
  }

const baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL_LOCAL;

const childFormDialog = (Props: paymentTypeProps) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();    
    const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState("");
    const [errormsg, setErrorMsg] = useState("");
    const [fullname, setFullName] = useState<string>('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>('');
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState<string>('');                 
    const [paymenttypes, setPaymenttypes] = useState(Props.paymenttype)       

    useLayoutEffect(()=>{
        setFullName(secureLocalStorage.getItem('fullname').toString());
        setEmail(secureLocalStorage.getItem('email').toString());        
        setPhone(secureLocalStorage.getItem('phone').toString());  
        //setPaymentType(Props.)      
    }, []);

    const validationSchema = yup.object({
        fullname: yup.string().required('Your full name is needed'),
        email: yup.string().required('An email address is needed'),
        phone: yup.string().required('Phone number is needed'),
        amount: yup.string().required('Please type an amount'),                 
        paymenttitle: yup.string().required('Please indicate title for this payment'),
        paymentdescription: yup.string(),                  
      });    
    
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            fullname: fullname, 
        email: email, 
        phone: phone, 
        amount: '',        
        paymenttitle: '',        
        paymentdescription: '',        
        },
        validationSchema: validationSchema, 
        onSubmit: async (values) => {            
                handleFormSubmit();   
        }  
    })

    const makePayment = () => {

    }

    const handleFormSubmit = () => {
        var data = {           
            fullname: formik.values.fullname,
            email: formik.values.email,
            phone: formik.values.phone,
            amount: formik.values.amount,    
            paymenttitle: formik.values.paymentdescription,
            paymentdescription: formik.values.paymentdescription,    

        }        
        
        if(paymenttypes =='A') {
            configPaymentAPI_A(data.amount, data.email, data.phone, data.fullname, data.paymenttitle, data.paymentdescription)
        }

        else{
                configPaymentAPI_B(data.email, data.amount)
        }
              
      } //function closed


  return <>
  <form style={{width: '100%}'}}>
        <div className="row px-3">  
        
<Grid container direction={"column"} spacing={2}>
<Grid item>
        <TextField 
              style ={{width: '100%'}} 
              label="Payment Title" 
              name="paymenttitle"
              placeholder="Payment Title" 
              variant="standard"
              type="text" 
              value={formik.values.paymenttitle}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              error={formik.touched.paymenttitle && Boolean(formik.errors.paymenttitle)}
              helperText={formik.touched.paymenttitle && formik.errors.paymenttitle}
              InputProps={{
                startAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="start">
                    <CallToActionIcon color="primary" />
                  </InputAdornment>
                ),
              }} />
</Grid>
        <Grid item>
        <TextField 
              style ={{width: '100%'}} 
              label="Full Name" 
              name="fullname"
              placeholder="Your Full Name" 
              variant="standard"
              type="text" 
              aria-readonly
              value={formik.values.fullname}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              error={formik.touched.fullname && Boolean(formik.errors.fullname)}
              helperText={formik.touched.fullname && formik.errors.fullname}
              InputProps={{
                startAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="start">
                    <PersonOutlineIcon color="primary" />
                  </InputAdornment>
                ),
              }} />
</Grid>
<Grid item>
        <TextField 
              style ={{width: '100%'}} 
              label="Email Address" 
              name="email"
              placeholder="Your Email" 
              variant="standard"
              type="email" 
              aria-readonly
              value={formik.values.email}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              error={formik.touched.email && Boolean(formik.errors.email)}
              helperText={formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email}
              InputProps={{
                startAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="start">
                    <EmailIcon color="primary" />
                  </InputAdornment>
                ),
              }} />
</Grid>
<Grid item>
        <TextField 
              style ={{width: '100%'}} 
              label="Phone Number" 
              name="phone"
              placeholder="Your Phone Number" 
              variant="standard"
              type="number" 
              aria-readonly
              value={formik.values.phone}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              error={formik.touched.phone && Boolean(formik.errors.phone)}
              helperText={formik.touched.phone && formik.errors.phone}
              InputProps={{
                startAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="start">
                    <PhoneIphoneIcon color="primary" />
                  </InputAdornment>
                ),
              }} />
</Grid>
<Grid item>
        <TextField 
              style ={{width: '100%'}} 
              label="Amount" 
              name="amount"
              placeholder="Amount To Be Paid" 
              variant="standard"
              type="number" 
              value={formik.values.amount}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              error={formik.touched.amount && Boolean(formik.errors.amount)}
              helperText={formik.touched.amount && formik.errors.amount}
              InputProps={{
                startAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="start">
                    <CallToActionIcon color="primary" />
                  </InputAdornment>
                ),
              }} />
</Grid>
<Grid item>
        <TextField 
              style ={{width: '100%'}} 
              label="Payment Description" 
              name="paymentdescription"
              placeholder="Type some notes for this payment" 
              variant="standard"
              type="text" 
              value={formik.values.paymentdescription}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              error={formik.touched.paymentdescription && Boolean(formik.errors.paymentdescription)}
              helperText={formik.touched.paymentdescription && formik.errors.paymentdescription}
              InputProps={{
                startAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="start">
                    <EventNoteIcon color="primary" />
                  </InputAdornment>
                ),
              }} />
</Grid>
<Grid item>
<Button 
type="submit"
variant="contained"  
startIcon={<SendIcon />} 
disableRipple 
>Remit Your Payment </Button>
</Grid>

</Grid>   
  </div>
  </form>
  </>
  
}

export default childFormDialog


********************THE PARENT FORM THAT CALL/INVOKE THE DIALOG ONCLICK OF A LINK

--->Parent.tsx

const [paymentTypState, setPaymentTypState] = useState<string>('');
  const [modalDisplay, setModalDisplay] = useState<boolean>(false); 
  const [close, setClose] = useState<boolean>(true); 
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false); 


const onclickPaymentA = () => {
    setOpen(true); 
    setPaymentTypState('A');  
}

const onclickPaymentB = () => {
    setOpen(true); 
    setPaymentTypState('B');  
}

const handleDialogOnSubmit = () => {

  }

return <>
<a onClick={onclickPaymentA}>
      <img src="../assets/images/paymentA.png" style={{width:300, height: 150}}/>
      </a>

<a onClick={onclickPaymentB}>
      <img src="../assets/images/paymentB.png" style={{width:300, height: 150}}/>
      </a>


<ReusableDialog
         show = { open }
         title = 'Top Up Your Wallet'
         body = {<childFormDialog paymenttype={paymentTypState} />}
         closeDialog = {() => setOpen(false) }        
         onSubmitButtonClicked = { handleDialogOnSubmit }
      />
</>

**********THE ROUTER OF THE APPLICATION THAT USES BROWSERROUTER

import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Login from './Login';
import Register from './Register';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import Parent from './Parent';


 <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}>
        </Route>
 <Route path="/register" element={<Register />}>
        </Route>
<Route path="/dashboard" element={<AuthenticatedRoute element={<Dashboard />} />}>
 <Route path="/parent" element={<AuthenticatedRoute element={<Parent />} />}>
```

I can navigate from other page to Parent.tsx and I can navigate from Parent.tsx to other pages. I don't have childFormDialog that will be displayed in the Material UI Dialog in the router because no page calls the childFormDialog through hyperlink or the menu link. The childFormDialog is called from the Parent.tsx file and it should displays in the Reusable Dialog Component on the same page.

The current behavior of the form when I click on the hyperlink is that it only shows a blank page and remain on the same URL without reloading/refreshing the page. The expected behavior is for the Material UI Dialog to display with the childFormDialog component displays in the Material UI Dialog.
I will appreciate your kind assistance

Answer (score 0):

If you forgot to wrap your app in a [BrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router) and attempt to instantiate the `useNavigate` hook, then your `childFormDialog` component would quietly fail and not render anything.

Comment: I can navigate correctly because all my navigations are working from page to page. Understand that I am not navigating to another page from parent component, I only wanted to display the childFormComponent on the ParentForm using the reusable modal dialog.  I’m not navigating to another page onclick of button or hyperlink, I just wanted to display child form on parent form using the dialog.

Comment: I placed your code in a sandbox and I see the modal popup when clicking one of the images(broken) --- https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/exciting-forest-bfk84u --- Are you sure Parent.tsx is wrapped in router? The only way I could reproduce your problem is by not wrapping in router, and leaving the `useNavigate` hook in the Parent component --- then I see no modal popup.

Comment: The Modal Dialog is not wrapped in the router because I don’t plan to move from one page to the dialog. Do I need router in this code because router is all about navigating from one page to another. If I need to move the dialog in the router, do I need to it like other pages? Currently the Reusable Dialog is not wrapped in router.

Comment: sure the Parent.tsx is wrapped in router because I navigate from one page to the Parent.tsx where I clicked the hyperlink that open the dialog. The Parent.tsx is wrapped in router but the ChildForm and Reusable Dialog component are not. Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the component that wraps `Parent.tsx` in BrowserRouter.

Comment: Thank you @Wesley  LeMahieu, this is the file where I have all routers:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Parent from './Parent';

 <Route path="/parent" element={<AuthenticatedRoute element={<Parent />} />}>

```

I can navigate from other page to Parent.tsx and I can navigate from Parent.tsx to other pages. I don't have childForm that will be displayed in the Dialog in the router. The childForm is called from the Parent.tsx file on the same page.

Comment: You should edit and place that code in the original post instead of creating an answer to your own question. Also, what does `AuthenticatedRoute` contain?

Comment: AuthenticateRoute is to protect the route(page) against UnAuthenticated access. The page is designed to be called after a user login. User Login worked and i can click on a menu link and navigate to Parent.tsx. What I expected is to click on on a hyperlink in Parent.tsx and display ChildFormDialog.tsx component in a Reusable Dialog Component. That is just what I was trying to do.

Comment: i have added the code to the main post. Thank you